# Add network adapter to VMware

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, vmware

I got image of Debian 6 virtual machine. I run it on VMware without problems, but there is no network card configured:

[image]

Vmware settings:
[image]

How to tell Debian to use vmware network card and bring networking there?

Answer (score 1):

In the settings to the right under `Network Connection`, you want to select `Bridged` and also `Replicate physical network connection state`. Afterwards, reboot the `Debian` VM and you'll have a network adapter named something along the lines of `ens33`.

The option that you have selected only allows the VM to communicate with the host.

If the network adapter still isn't appearing, power off the VM, go into the VM settings, select Add, and choose Network Adapater. Power the `Debian` VM back on and you'll see the adapter which will automatically be configured for `DHCP`. There'll be a section of it in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: And how to know exact name of adapter and how to make it work in Debian system?

Comment: @vico Run the same command that you did above `sudo ipconfig` and the name of the network adapter will begin with `ens`. Basically, it will be the adapter listed after `lo`. It will automatically be configured to use `DHCP` so if that's what you want then you won't need to do anything as it will pull it's networking information from the same DHCP server that your host is using.

Comment: I did `bridged` and `replicate`, but still have only one `lo` adapter with ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: @vico See the update in my answer.